# How to create a transparent web view in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m parsing an rss feed and loading it in webview..ive placed an image in the background of the webview.wat i want is a transparent webview which shows the image and also the parsed content ....below is the code..cud u guys help me out...the itemSummary contains the parsed feed

```
[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[item objectForKey:@"description"] baseURL:nil];

[self.itemSummary setClipsToBounds:YES];

self.itemSummary.opaque=NO;

self.itemSummary.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this discussion:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/9175823?messageID=9175823&

**Summary**

Make the UIWebView transparent:

```
[myWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myWebView setOpaque:NO];
```

Make the page itself transparent (use only one):

```
<body style="background-color: transparent">
body{background-color:transparent;}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort..i gave clean built and run on the above code it worked good...

Answer (score 1):

There is a BUG in UIWebView implementation, which is misleading for many developers including readers of this thread...

> If you set "backgroundColor" property to "ClearColor"  and "opaque"
> property to "NO"(unchecked) this should've worked... But it doesn't

Then the developers look for other flags, solutions etc.

The real solution is setting the backgroundColor in code, not in IB

**

> so (1) you should set "opaque" property to "NO" in IB,
>
> and then regardless (due to the BUG) of the "backgroundColor" property you set for the WebView in IB,
>
> you still HAVE TO (due to the BUG) (2) set the "backgroundColor" property in code,
> conveniently in "viewDidLoad" or "viewWillAppear"
>
> (1) + (2) does the magic...

**

Hope this helps

Comment: Aha.. good point. It needs to be done from code, not Interface Builder. Thank you